# How can i configure my testng.xml to run in the below mentioned way?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng-eclipse

In my testng.xml, am having two groups. I want it to run in the way like the below one

- First group suite
- First group test1
- First group test2
- Second group suite
- Second group test1
- Second group test2

But now its running in the way,

- First group suite
- Second group suite
- First group test1
- Second group test1
- First group test2
- Second group test2

Here is my testng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Techno suite">
   <test verbose="2" name="Sales Application">
       <groups>
           <run>
               <include name="sales App"></include>  
           </run>
       </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="maven.com.techno.automation.testcases.TC_01_Sales_LoginPage"/>
    </classes>
    </test>
     <test verbose="2" name="Login and Opportunity Update">
       <groups>
           <run>
               <include name="Web App"></include>  
           </run>
       </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="maven.com.te.automation.testcases.TC_01_LoginPage"/>
      <class name="maven.com.te.automation.testcases.TC_01_LoginPage"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Comment: Can you share the Testng.xml?

Comment: i have added testng.xml with the post.